# Sort a list of object w.r.t to a particular member/state

Tags: java, string, list, sorting

I have a list of java object that have 4 members.

```
int id;
String name;
String age;
int order;
```

I want to sort the list of this object w.r.t name

Comment: Shouldn't `age` be an number (`int` or `float`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort all member/state on behalf of value of **myString** i.e if myString is name then sort by name vice versa.

```
  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<com.MyObject>() {

          public int compare(com.MyObject object1, com.MyObject object2) {

            if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
            return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());

          }else if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("age")){
            return object1.getAge().compareTo(object2.getAge());

          }else{
            return object1.getOrder() - object2.getOrder();
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Either you implement a `Comparator` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    // add your objects to the list     

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
    });
}
```

Or you can implement the `Comparable` interface on `MyObject`:

```
class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
    int id;
    String name;
    String age;
    int order;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ....
    Collections.sort(list); // with the comparable interface
}
```

Comment: `o.name`: name is not static, use getter method instead

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Good point, you could however have the `Comparator` as a member class.

Comment: I am using these Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
in if else e.g if(myString.equals("name")){//sort by name} else{//sort by age}. BUT IT THROWS EXCEPTION.

Comment: Which exception does it throw? If it is a `NullPointerException` you need to 1) not have any null values or 2) make a null guard in your comparator. I would however recommend you having **two** `Comparator`s for the different tasks, one for sorting for `name` and one of sorting for `age`.

Comment: I am using seperate Comparator for both. It throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //class is in which I am using this code

Comment: Hum, that sounds tricky, post another SO question for that problem (and also try to isolate the problem).

Comment: I was getting exception because I using 'Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<com.MyObject>()' many times. I posted answer for the working code.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a comparator that compares 2 objects from that type by their names, and sort using this comparator:

```
private static class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyType>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(MyType o1, MyType o2)
    {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }

}
```

And then sort:

```
 Collections.sort(list, myComparator);
```

Comment: I am using these Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
in if else e.g if(myString.equals("name")){//sort by name} else{//sort by age}. BUT IT THROWS EXCEPTION.

Comment: I was getting exception because I using 'Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<com.MyObject>()' many times. I posted answer for the working code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Arrays.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29).